# Passing function as argument to Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, function, methods, arguments

I'd like to pass a `C` function as an argument to an Objective-C method, to then act as a callback. The function has type `int (*callback)(void *arg1, int arg2, char **arg3, char **arg4)`.

I keep getting the syntax wrong. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you show what you're using right now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a slightly more complete alternative to KKK4SO's example:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

// typedef for the callback type
typedef int (*callbackType)(int x, int y);

@interface Foobar : NSObject
// without using the typedef
- (void) callFunction:(int (*)(int x, int y))callback;
// with the typedef
- (void) callFunction2:(callbackType)callback;
@end

@implementation Foobar
- (void) callFunction:(int (*)(int x, int y))callback {
    int ret = callback(5, 10);
    NSLog(@"Returned: %d", ret);
}
// same code for both, really
- (void) callFunction2:(callbackType)callback {
    int ret = callback(5, 10);
    NSLog(@"Returned: %d", ret);
}
@end

static int someFunction(int x, int y) {
    NSLog(@"Called: %d, %d", x, y);
    return x * y;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Foobar *baz = [[Foobar alloc] init];
    [baz callFunction:someFunction];
    [baz callFunction2:someFunction];
    [baz release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, it's the same as anything else, except that without the typedef, you don't specify the name of the callback when specifying the type of the parameter (the `callback` parameter in either `callFunction:` method).  So that detail might have been tripping you up, but it's simple enough.

Comment: Right - I was missing the typedef declaration. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following peice of code worked,absolutely fine . just check

```
typedef int (*callback)(void *arg1, int arg2, char **arg3, char **arg4);

int f(void *arg1, int arg2, char **arg3, char **arg4)
{
    return 9;
}

-(void) dummy:(callback) a
{
    int i = a(NULL,1,NULL,NULL);
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
}

-(void) someOtherMehtod
{
    callback a = f;
    [self dummy:a];
}
```

Comment: Right - I was missing the typedef declaration. Thanks.